# Detecting which webkit/moz/etc. prefix to display

Tags: php, css, user-agent, vendor-prefix

I've been working on a CSS minifier for PHP that's done except for one thing:

I'd like to have it detect the user's browser and determine whether the user needs border-radius, -webkit-border-radius, -moz-border-radius, etc. So that I dont have to use the very long and annoying groups.

This would either detect all instances of -webkit, -moz, etc. border-radius and merge them OR I would place {vendor}border-radius into the CSS file which would then be replaced by either -webkit-, -moz-, or nothing. The first one is ideal because I'd like for it to be expandable to other projects.

For the life of me, I *can't* figure out a working PHP implementation that accurately detects which prefix to use (and I've googled/searched everywhere I could think of).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just serve static CSS with all the vendor prefixes in it?  There's no negative consequences to doing that, other than the stylesheet being a bit bigger.  Besides, there's no reliable way for PHP to know what CSS capabilities the client has.  What happens when Mozilla update firefox to use the official border-radius property and drop support for -moz-border-radius?

Comment: @GordonM ideally it would just check if it *only* supported -moz (e.g. mozilla until 4.0) or *only* supported -webkit (Chrome until 5.0, Safari until 5.0, iOS Safari until 4.0, Android until 2.2). In those very specific cases, it'd add a prefix, otherwise it would serve up a generic prefixless "border-radius" or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue here is that PHP (the server) won't know the CSS capabilities of your browser off-hand (the client). The only information that's remotely close to identifying a browser that would get sent to PHP is the user-agent string. Even then, you would still need to research the CSS capabilities of a specific version of a specific browser or engine, based on what you find through parsing the user-agent string, and hard-code some decision-making code based on that information.

I think that's the main liability of trying to use server-side code to determine the CSS capabilities of a client. There may be others, but this seems the biggest hurdle, unfortunately.

On the client side, there exist scripts like [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree) that make adding prefixes a trivial job; just serve your minified CSS with only the unprefixed properties and rules, and let the script add the prefixes for you based on what it knows about the browser (that the server doesn't).

The first paragraph from this entry in its [FAQ](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/#faq) also seems worth a read:

> #### “Something like this belongs to the server-side”
>
> A server side script would need to add all prefixes, making the size of the CSS file considerably larger. **Also, it should maintain a list of features that need prefixes, or add them all and unnecessarily bloat the stylesheet.** -prefix-free automatically detects what needs a prefix and what doesn’t.

As well as an [interview with its author](http://css-tricks.com/five-questions-with-lea-verou/#lea-question-2), which it links to:

> #### "This is something better done on the server. Do it once instead of on every pageload"
>
> What -prefix-free exactly does, is impossible to do in the server. -prefix-free detects which features need a prefix and only adds it if needed. Also, it automatically detects which properties are available that need a prefix. It doesn't have to keep lists of which prefixes to add for which features, everything gets feature detected, and thus is very future proof. **With preprocessors, lists need to be maintained about this sort of stuff. Such lists are doomed to be incomplete and quickly get out of date. Every server-side prefixer I ever tried fails in a number of cases.**

*(Emphases mine.)*

Comment: I'm not too worried about the user spoofing a user agent as if they spoof a user agent it's their loss. I'm primarily looking to check if the browser *only* supports -webkit, *only* supports -moz, and otherwise simply serve up an unprefixed version (the minimum number of characters).

I may just stick with the unprefixed version as it seems supported by practically any remotely modern browser.

Comment: You're right - UA spoofing is a very minor issue (hence the one-liner). I'll remove it altogether as it's insignificant. The issue of knowing which browsers support what, though, remains the biggest problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, BoltClock. I've decided I'm going to take a very passive approach and detect only a few known cases of browsers needing special support (as mentioned in the comment section above) and feed them their prefix. Other than that, I'll stick with the no UA prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Sniff for the user agent of the browser and then set php conditional statments. I've quickly pasted the script I use for my webapp because I'm kinda busy so can't rewrite it for you, but you can google the user agents of different browsers and modify it as needed.

```
<?php
    $iPod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
    $iPhone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $iPad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    $Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $Blackberry = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Blackberry");
    $Playbook = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Playbook");
    $Mango = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mango");
    $webOS = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
?>
```

Alternatively, in css just set a class that uses all three and just set that class to whatever element you need to. This, in any case, is the easiest and most practical solution. Again, modify as needed.

```
.border-radius{
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: And what if I spoof my user agent to read `iPod iPhone iPad Android Blackberry Playbook Mango webOS windows macos osx linux ubuntu debian redhat`?

Comment: anyone who spoofs their user agent to read something other than what it is probably doesnt specifically care about your border-radius and probably has a more specific reason for doing so.

Comment: They probably do, like trying to exercise possible bugs that they can exploit.  Honestly, just putting all the vendor prefixes in a static CSS file is the better solution in all respects except size of the file, and as it gets cached that's only going to impact first load.  minifying the CSS (stripping whitespace and comments) and using mod_gzip can lessen the impact of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your question but you can use PrefixFree instead of reinventing the wheel.

look at it's detail here:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/12/prefixfree-break-free-from-css-prefix-hell/

Regarding your question:

You can use php get_browser() to determine the user browser and do as required.

In my experience, avoiding prefixes wouldn't decrease the css size so much. you can instead GZIP the file, it will affect css file so much and decrease the difference between all prefix or one prefix more even.

Comment: I looked at that about 10 minutes ago and got excited, then I realized it's Javascript. Mine is a CSS minifier meant for server-side compression.

Comment: Please do not post an answer if you know that it is not an answer. You can [post a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) instead.

Comment: It's an answer, but from different aspect!

Comment: You want to minify css delivering it to the client?